# Is there a way to get all servlet filters from the ApplicationFilterChain?

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I have multiple custom made Java libraries which use `javax.servlet.Filter` mechanism and I want to ensure that the developer that integrates the libraries doesn't create a custom application filter with  `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`.
Also guys if you know a method to collect all `ApplicationFilterConfig` from the `ApplicationFilterChain` and their filter's `Order` would be awesome.

I thought that when Spring initializes the context to check the if there are multiple filters with highest precedence or maybe when registering the filters (if there is any SpringFilterResister that I could implement or hook to).

Thanks!

**Later edit:**
Since I didn't find a way to get the `Order` of a `Filter` I just validated if other client tried to register a `Bean` with `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE`. Before showing the code, there are 2 ways of registering a Filter into the Filter chain:
1. Implement `javax.servlet.Filter` and annotate with `@Component` (by default has lowest precedence)
2. Use a `FilterRegistrationBean.class` under a `@Configuration` class.
These being said, I just check if somebody used these 2 ways of registering Filters:

```java
@ManagedBean
public class MyServletContextInitializer implements ServletContextInitializer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        Map<String, ? extends FilterRegistration> filters = servletContext.getFilterRegistrations();

        //check for @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) annotations
        List<String> result = filters.keySet().stream()
                .filter(beanName -> context.getBean(beanName)
                        .getClass().getAnnotation(Order.class).value() == Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());


        if(result.size()>1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("message");
        }

        //check for FilterRegistrationBean 
        if(context.getBean(FilterRegistrationBean.class).getOrder() == Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("message");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope will help others! Cheers!